# Is there a way to add a type for .settings files?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

In Visual Studio's Select a Type Dialog Box from the Settings file designer, you can select several types from the .NET Framework. Is there a way one can register or add a custom type to that treeview?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/776fzdxt.aspx

Comment: Did you try the "Browse..." item from that list?

Comment: Yes that is the dialog I want to add my types to.

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: Hi, I have changed my answer. This time with more care about what was being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I see I missuderstood the question, sorry...

I managed to add a type to it, by adding a reference to another project with types marked with  `SerializableAttribute`.

Comment: That is not what I'm talking about.

Comment: Sorry... I have changed my answer! Fast reading sometimes is not enough.

Comment: I think that may be its because it has needs to compile the type before being able to serialize it. Just guessing.